# While Executing View

Tags: jpa, struts2

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-06-21 11:53:58.648--UnitOfWork(1322878)--Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130315-93567e3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.ID => 51
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.a2bFirstLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.warfberth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.unberthingBerth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.berth => GJK
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.van => 55
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.unberthingLastLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.b2aLastLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.WarfingFirstLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.a2bBerth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.berthingFirstLine => 2013-06-05 12:43:00.0
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.warfingLastLine => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BerthOccupation sql="SELECT ID, a2bFirstLine, warfberth, unberthingBerth, berth, van, unberthingLastLine, b2aLastLine, WarfingFirstLine, a2bBerth, berthingFirstLine, warfingLastLine FROM IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation")
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130315-93567e3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.ID => 51
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.a2bFirstLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.warfberth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.unberthingBerth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.berth => GJK
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.van => 55
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.unberthingLastLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.b2aLastLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.WarfingFirstLine => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.a2bBerth => null
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.berthingFirstLine => 2013-06-05 12:43:00.0
    IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation.warfingLastLine => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BerthOccupation sql="SELECT ID, a2bFirstLine, warfberth, unberthingBerth, berth, van, unberthingLastLine, b2aLastLine, WarfingFirstLine, a2bBerth, berthingFirstLine, warfingLastLine FROM IPORTMAN_GPL_SITEDB_090520131300.IPORTMAN.Berth_Occupation")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.nullPrimaryKeyInBuildingObject(QueryException.java:912)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1589)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1554)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:411)
    at env.jspreports.kpis.KPIDAO.getBerthOccupancyXML(KPIDAO.java:550)
    at env.jspreports.kpis.KpiAction.generateBerthOccupancy(KpiAction.java:573)
    at env.jspreports.kpis.KpiAction.generateKPIs(KpiAction.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at env.actionitems.struts.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:43)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at entity.jpa.EntityInterceptor.intercept(EntityInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:95)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am new in using Views
I have created a view "Berth Occupation".And while executing ,i am facing some problem.
It was saying null cannot be accepted in primary key.

Thanks in advance.Please explain me why this was happened

Answer (score 0):

```
...Berth_Occupation.warfingLastLine => null)]
during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  
Primary keys must not contain null.
```

I think it is self-explaining. You have (erroneously?) set the `warfingLastLine` as part of the primary key, and set it to null.

Solutions are:

- do not use it as primary key (you have an ID field, maybe you want only that as PK ?), or
- always set its value...